# Pre populating the dropdown value inside ng-repeat in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options

I have an array of objects. I have three properties `attorneyId, attorneyName and attorneyList`. The `attorneyList` array should be a drop down. If `attorneyId = attorneyName = null` then 
dropdown will only show `Choose attorney`. If `attorneyId != null` and `attorneyName != null`, the dropdown should display what ever the value is present in `attorneyId` and `attorneyName`.

For this i am preparing an object `selectedAttorney = {id:list.attorneyId, name:list.attorneyName}` and passing this to `ng-model` of select. When i change the value in dropdown, i am getting the correct values into the `selectedAttorney`. But if there some value present for `attorneyId` and `attorneyName`, the dropdown is not pre populating the value.

HTML :

```
<div ng-repeat = 'list in List'>
  <div class="width-200" ng-init="selectedAttorney = {id:list.attorneyId, name:list.attorneyName}">
    {{selectedAttorney}}
    <select ng-model="selectedAttorney" ng-options="attorney.name for attorney in list.attorneyList">
      <option value="">-- choose attorney --</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.List = [ {
  "attorneyId": "3",
  "attorneyName": "Robert",
  "attorneyList": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "sue" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "anthony" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Robert" },
    { "id": 4, "name": "George" },
    { "id": 5, "name": "Bruce" }
  ]
},
{
  "attorneyId": null,
  "attorneyName": null,
  "attorneyList": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "sue" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "anthony" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Robert" },
    { "id": 4, "name": "George" },
    { "id": 5, "name": "Bruce" }
  ]
}
];
```

Here is the plunker link.

http://plnkr.co/edit/eqBkX0DNleiFmlO5sm7J?p=preview

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Though your approach is right, I prefer writing my select boxes in this manner.

```
<select ng-model="selectedAttorney">
        <option 
           ng-repeat="attorney in list.attorneyList"
           title="{{attorney.name}}"
           ng-selected="{{attorney.id == selectedAttorney.id}}"
           value="{{attorney}}">{{attorney.name}}
       </option>
</select>
```

and here is the updated working demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/vCNOAPWlR6Mj1kFOgCKT?p=preview

Comment: How can i set some default text like `<option value="">-- choose attorney --</option>` if no item is selected?

Comment: @Yasser great answer +1 for you.But i have a doubt why OP way is not working he is assigning the object to selectedAttorney and  that is valid too.